# How to use a predefined lambda in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Kotlin coming from Java, and I stumbled upon an unexpected behavior.
I noticed, that in my below code, I seem to accidentally declare a new lambda at a bad position instead of *using* the one I already have. How can I fix this?

I wrote these two declarations:

```
/**
 * Dataclass used as an example.
 */
data class Meeple(var name: String, var color: String = "translucent")

/**
 * Function to map from a List<T> to a new List of equal length,
 * containing the ordered elements received by applying a Mapper's map
 * function to every element of the input List.
 *
 * @param T Type of input List-elements
 * @param O Type of output List-elements
 * @param mapper The mapping function applied to every input element.
 * @return The List of output elements received by applying the mapper on all
 * input elements.
 */
fun <T, O> List<T>.map(mapper: (T) -> O?): List<O?> {
    val target = ArrayList<O?>();

    for (t in this) {
        val mapped: O? = mapper.invoke(t)
        target.add(mapped);
    }

    return target;
}
```

The data class is just a dummy example of a simple object. The `List.map` extension function is meant to map from the elements of the list to a new type and return a new List of that new type, almost like a `Stream.map` would in Java.

I then create some dummy `Meeple`s and try to map them to their respective names:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val meeples = listOf(
        Meeple("Jim", "#fff"),
        Meeple("Cassidy"),
        Meeple("David", "#f00")
    )

    var toFilter: String = "Cassidy"
    val lambda: (Meeple) -> String? =
        { if (it.name == toFilter) null else it.name }
    toFilter = "Jim"

    for (name in meeples.map { lambda }) {
        println(name ?: "[anonymous]") // This outputs "(Meeple) -> kotlin.String?" (x3 because of the loop)
    }
}
```

I did this to check the behavior of the lambda, and whether it would later filter "Jim" or "Cassidy", my expectation being the later, as that was the state of `toFilter` at lambda initialization.

However I got an entirely different result. The `invoke` method, though described by IntelliJ as being `(T) -> O?` seems to yield the name of the lambda instead of the name of the `Meeple`.

It seems, that the call to `meeples.map { lambda }` does not bind the lambda as I expected, but creates a new lambda, that returns `lambda` and probably internally calls `toString` on that as well.

How would I actually invoke the real lambda method, instead of declaring a new one?

Comment: Just in case, the [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) function exists in the Kotlin standard library.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I suspected as much, though this was more of a field example to get to write some lambdas. Thanks for the hint though :)

Comment: I figured it out. It needs to be a simple parameter, instead of being wrapped in `{  }`. It should have looked like this: `for (name in meeples.map(lambda)) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned in the comments you figured out that you were passing a new lambda that returns your original lambda.

As for the `toFilter` value changing: The lambda function is like any other interface. As you have defined it, it captures the `toFilter` variable, so it will always use the current value of it when the lambda is executed. If you want to avoid capturing the variable, copy its current value into the lambda when you define the lambda. There are various ways to do this. One way is to copy it to a local variable first.

```
var toFilter: String = "Cassidy"
val constantToFilter = toFilter
val lambda: (Meeple) -> String? =
    { if (it.name == constantToFilter) null else it.name }
toFilter = "Jim"
```

Pretty much anything you can do with Stream in Java, you can do to an Iterable directly in Kotlin. The `map` function is already available, as mentioned in the comments.

---

Edit: Since you mentioned Java behavior in the comments.

Java can capture member variables, but local variables have to be marked `final` for the compiler to allow you to pass them to a lambda or interface. So in this sense they capture values only (unless you pass member variable). The equivalent to Java's `final` for a local variable in Kotlin is `val`.

Kotlin is more lenient than Java in this situation, and *also* allows you to pass a non-final local variable (`var`) to an interface or lambda, and it captures the variable in this case. This is what your original code is doing.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the turnout. A funny aspect for me as a Java-developer, where lambdas capture values, not variables, but this is understandable. Thank you for the answer regarding general interfaces.

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question,not sure why you accepted it!

Comment: I found my own answer, as mentioned in the answer. But the answer to my inner answer helps me a lot.

Comment: I was answering the secondary implied question, why the lambda doesn't return `"Cassidy"`.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Thanks for pointing it out so I could clarify and not confuse future readers.

Comment: @TreffnonX I added some info comparing the Java and Kotlin behavior. Kotlin is not behaving differently, just more leniently.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have found the issue as you mention in comments, I am adding this answer with some details to help any future readers.

So when you create lambda using

```
val lambda: (Meeple) -> String? = { if (it.name == toFilter) null else it.name }
```

This basically translates to

```
final Function1 lambda = (Function1)(new Function1() {
   public Object invoke(Object var1) {
      return this.invoke((Meeple)var1);
   }

   @Nullable
   public final String invoke(@NotNull Meeple it) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(it, "it");
      return Intrinsics.areEqual(it.getName(), (String)toFilter.element) ? null : it.getName();
    }
});
```

**Now correct way to pass this to your map method would be as you have mentioned in comments**

```
name in meeples.map(lambda)
```

but instead of `(lambda)` you wrote `{ lambda }`, this is the [trailing lambda convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas)

```
name in meeples.map { lambda }  
//  if the last parameter of a function is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses:
// If the lambda is the only argument in that call, the parentheses can be omitted entirely
```

**this creates a new lambda which returns the lambda we defined above, this line basically gets translated to following**

```
HomeFragmentKt.map(meeples, (Function1)(new Function1() {
     public Object invoke(Object var1) {
         return this.invoke((Meeple)var1);
      }

      @Nullable
      public final Function1 invoke(@NotNull Meeple it) {
          Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(it, "it");
          return lambda; // It simply returns the lambda you defined, and the code to filter never gets invoked
       }
  }))
```